# Can I get TypeScript autocomplete in this function while still inferring types?

Tags: typescript

I am writing a set of factory functions, which will each return part of a larger overall object. As it is a complex type, I want to be able to use intellisense to help me write these functions.

I don't know what return type to annotate the functions with to ensure I get intellisense/autocomplete. I have tried three things so far. For these examples, you can assume `FooType` is defined as:

```
interface FooType {
    prop1: boolean;
    prop2: boolean;
    ...
}
```

### Option One

I can use type inference to automatically determine type for my functions, but then I don't get any type inference.

```
function PartialFooMaker1() {
   return {
        prop1: true,
        // I want autocomplete in here
   }
}
function PartialFooMaker2() {
   return {
        prop2: true,
        // I also want autocomplete in here
   }
}

export const Foo: FooType = Object.assign({}, PartialFooMaker1(),PartialFooMaker2());
```

### Option Two

I can specify the full type as the function return type, but that (correctly) triggers a compile error if I omit some properties.

```
function PartialFooMaker1(): FooType {
   return {
        prop1: true,
        // I have autocomplete, but TS complains about the lack of prop2
   }
}
function PartialFooMaker2(): FooType {
   return {
        prop2: true,
        // I have autocomplete, but TS complains about the lack of prop1
   }
}

export const Foo: FooType = Object.assign({}, PartialFooMaker1(),PartialFooMaker2());
```

### Option Three

I can specify the full type as the function return type, but that (correctly) triggers a compile error if I omit some properties.

```
function PartialFooMaker1(): Partial<FooType> {
   return {
        prop1: true,
        // I have autocomplete! :)
   }
}
function PartialFooMaker2(): Partial<FooType> {
   return {
        prop2: true,
        // I have autocomplete! :)
   }
}

// the compile error is now here - TS doesn't know that prop1 and prop2 are present
export const Foo: FooType = Object.assign({}, PartialFooMaker1(),PartialFooMaker2());
```

I have also considered splitting up FooType into well-defined subtypes, and then recombining with union types, but in reality it is a complex derived type, so it would be hard for me to split up.

Is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Could you please elaborate on what your partial makers do? Their behavior and return types would help.

Comment: They literally do what is in the code sample - they're just shortcuts to create object constants.

Comment: @KarolMajewski I have expanded the examples to be even clearer.

Comment: I would go with the `Partial` approach, making it compile is not the issue (just cast `{}` in the assign to `FooType`), checking the union to be correct is however...

Comment: @H.B. Yes, I can make it compile but I lose type-safety by doing that. If I forget to include `prop1`, no one will know!

Comment: @ChristopherLittle: Is using `Pick` an option? You will have to list the keys to some degree (if you cannot just use `keyof PartOfFoo`).

Answer (score 0):

If you can (reasonably) use `Pick`:

```
interface NamePart { first: string; last: string }
interface AgePart  { age: number; }
interface FooType extends NamePart, AgePart
{
    oneMoreThing: string;
}

function PartialFooMaker1(): Pick<FooType, keyof NamePart | "oneMoreThing">
{
    return {
        first: "Steve",
        last: "Stevenson",
        oneMoreThing: "!",
    }
}
function PartialFooMaker2(): Pick<FooType, keyof AgePart>
{
    return {
        age: 42
    }
}

export const Foo: FooType = { ...PartialFooMaker1(), ...PartialFooMaker2() };
```

The first part will have the resolved type `Pick<FooType, "first" | "last" | "oneMoreThing">` which combines correctly with `Pick<FooType, "age">` to form a complete instance of `FooType`.

Keys can be unioned from type-safe literals and `keyof` expressions.

Comment: It would be nice if the second type argument to `Pick` could be inferred from the returned object...

Comment: I think this might be what I end up doing. It's a bit verbose having to spell out the properties, and it doesn't help for deeper objects, but it's better than nothing!

Answer (score 0):

`Partial` means zero or more properties in common. What you want is `Pick`:

```
function PartialFooMaker1(): Pick<FooType, 'prop1'> {
  return {
       prop1: true,
       // I want autocomplete in here
  };
}

function PartialFooMaker2(): Pick<FooType, 'prop2'> {
  return {
       prop2: true,
       // I also want autocomplete in here
  };
}
```

Using `Pick` will require you to provide the properties which you want to pick in advance, but it will give you IntelliSense in return.

Another option would be to tell TypeScript that every factory function returns a piece of `FooType`.

```
type Slice<T extends object> = { [P in keyof T]: Pick<T, P> }[keyof T];

type FooFactory = () => Slice<FooType>;

const PartialFooMaker3: FooFactory = () => {
  return {
    prop1: false,
  };
};
```

This won't require explicit return types, but the inferred type will always be *a* slice of `FooType` — not *the* slice of `FooType` you are actually returning. That's why I recommend taking the #1 approach. IntelliSense won't suggest what you should return if you don't say what the desired return type should be.